# Transform <P> element into <H1> in PDF file

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm working in a tool that improves the accessibility on PDF files, using PDFBox. The problem is that I need some type of function that lets me change the tag of a PDF element automatically.

For example, given a PDF, I want to change certain **P** element to a **H1** element: Here is how the **P** element [displays on Adobe Acrobat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAQXl.jpg)

This is the [text that correponds to that **P** tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qieY.jpg)

I can change the element tag manually (using Adobe Acrobat) without problem, resulting in a **H1** element that contains

```
1. Introduction
```

This is [how the changed element would display after assigning the **H1** tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEk3e.jpg)

Can I achieve this, by code, using some type of function, preferably provided by PDFBox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: What created the PDF in the first place? Or are you "imagining" a generic solution? You will never get to gwnweric without years of custom code.

Comment: @KevinBrown Right now I am working with a PDF file that has all the text classified in <P> tags

Comment: @aled I can share the code but keep in mind that I only need a certain PDFBox function that I cannot find to transform a P element into a H1 element. The algorithm that detects which P's have to be changed is already coded, that's why I didn't share the code in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an XY problem, like looking for one needle amongst many in a haystack of many straws.

[image]

As a human I determine **subjectively** the Unordered Paragraph should be along with another item both be classified humanly as a "Heading", I can also reorder at the same time.

Thus as fast as I decide, then I can alter the required outcome, faster than write a decision as a program. Thus cheaper in time of ownership, to use a lower cost pre-flight attendant than build an algorithm for each subjective case.

You need to write a program that replicates a human, hence the advice is use sighted humans for human accessibility tag checking.

Actually I am impressed how well an online service resolved the order for me (https://pdfix.net/pricing/) thus correctly reversed 29 & 30, it's still a Paragraph same as the page header, but now I only need to change both to H1 and manually fix 6 other failures.

[image]

Comment: I understand your points about subjectively classifying the elements as Headings, but I already have a simple algorithm that detects which text needs to be converted to Heading 1 (basically, I detect if the line starts with "1."). That's why I only need the function that can convert a <P> element into a <H1> one. Thanks for the response.